# Adding 300 spaces with PHP for text file

Tags: php, whitespace

I want to add 300 spaces to a text file with PHP. I can't use `&nbsp` as you already knew (.txt format, not HTML), so how to do this?

So this code counts numbers as you can see, I need 300 white-spaces.

```
$spaces = 0; // will become 300 spaces

 while ($spaces < 300)
 {
    $spaces++;
 }
```

and for testing how many white-spaces I have I will use

```
substr_count($spaces, ' ');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of creating a loop to build them, just use the following

```
$padded_text = str_pad($some_text, 300, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Anything less than 300 chars big, gets spaces added, and depending where you want those spaces, you can try using STR_PAD_RIGHT or STR_PAD_BOTH.  And if you have no characters at all, it will generate it full of 300 spaces, this will be faster than using a loop.

Now if you simply want to add 300 spaces (not pad it so that there will be less than 300 spaces) you'll want to use

```
$spaces = str_repeat(' ', 300);
```

Comment: `$zerospaces = "hello"; $spaces = str_pad($zerospaces, 300, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT); $spacecount = substr_count($spaces, " "); echo $spacecount.$spaces;` has a output of `295 hello` and no 300 white-spaces between `count and hello`

Comment: @F4LLCON if you just want 300 spaces, not padded text that's 300 chars, then run  str_pad  on an empty variable, like this

$spaces = str_pad("", 300, " ");

Comment: @TravisO Better yet, if you're not actually doing any padding, just use [`str_repeat(' ', 300);`](http://php.net/str_repeat).

Comment: @TravisO and Wiseguy thank you both, both solutions worked good. I will use `str_repeat(' ', 300);`

Comment: @Wiseguy you are correct, I thought he wanted padding then realized he just wants 300 spaces, I updated my answer above to reflect both scenarios.